# Void to String method conversion with nested methods

Tags: c#, methods

```
    public void Print() {
        Print(root, 4);
    }

    private void Print(Node node, int padding) {
        if (node != null) {
            if (node.rChild != null) {
                Print(node.rChild, padding + 4);
            }
            if (padding > 0) {
                Console.Write(" ".PadLeft(padding));
            }
            if (node.rChild != null) {
                Console.Write("/\n");
                Console.Write(" ".PadLeft(padding));
            }
            Console.Write(node.value.ToString() + "\n ");
            if (node.lChild != null) {
                Console.Write(" ".PadLeft(padding) + "\\\n");
                Print(node.lChild, padding + 4);
            }
        }
    }
```

this code returns a nice format log in console. like below

```
        6
     /
    5
     \
        4
 /
3
 \
    2
     \
        2
```

now when i convert the void to string format, it becomes messy and it doesn't seem to work. since I have nested methods.

So I am currently lost in the conversion from void to string

Comment: Where is the code you tried? We can't tell you how to fix it if you don't show us.

Comment: its just adding a bunch of variables and returns within each other and changing the void to String. the code i wrote is off topic and in theory shouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concise way to approach this would be:

1. Replace each of your `if` statements with a conditional statement that either produces the stuff inside the `if` statement or an empty string.
2. Combine all the pieces together using `+`
3. Return the result

That would give you this:

```
private string Print(Node node, int padding)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        return 
            (node.rChild != null 
                ? Print(node.rChild, padding + 4) 
                : "") +
            (padding > 0 
                ? " ".PadLeft(padding) 
                : "") +
            (node.rChild != null 
                ? "/\n" + " ".PadLeft(padding) 
                : "") +
            node.value.ToString() + "\n " +
            (node.lChild != null 
                ? " ".PadLeft(padding) + "\\\n" + Print(node.lChild, padding + 4) 
                : "");
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So instead of printing out the values, you want it to return the tree as a string.

Well, to do this, you just need to change every `Console.Write` method call to append the string your were printing to a big string, and every `Print` method call to append the return value of `Print` to a big string. And at the end return this big string

Basically, imagine the "big string" is the console.

You can use the `StringBuilder` class as this big string that I'm talking about. Let's create one at the start of the print method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
```

Now we need to look for these two patterns and change them.

We change:

```
Console.Write(XXX);
```

to

```
sb.Append(XXX);
```

and change

```
Print(XXX, XXX);
```

to

```
sb.Append(Print(XXX, XXX))
```

Now the method looks like this:

```
private string Print(Node node, int padding) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
    if (node != null) {
        if (node.rChild != null) {
            sb.Append(Print(node.rChild, padding + 4));
        }
        if (padding > 0) {
            sb.Append(" ".PadLeft(padding));
        }
        if (node.rChild != null) {
            sb.Append("/\n");
            sb.Append(" ".PadLeft(padding));
        }
        sb.Append(node.value.ToString() + "\n ");
        if (node.lChild != null) {
            sb.Append(" ".PadLeft(padding) + "\\\n");
            sb.Append(Print(node.lChild, padding + 4));
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString ();
}
```

After this, you should be able to change the parameterless `Print` method to return a string on your own.